# Chainlink Operator.sol not compiling - TypeError: The suffixes .offset and .slot can only be used on storage variables

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I'm trying to compile a contract that imports Chainlink's Operator.sol, but when I do I get the below error.

Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/Operator.sol";
```

Error:

```
@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/Operator.sol:540:37: TypeError: The suffixes .offset and .slot can only be used on storage variables.
      firstDataWord := calldataload(data.offset)
                                    ^---------^
```

Relevant part of Operator.sol:

```
  modifier validateMultiWordResponseId(bytes32 requestId, bytes calldata data) {
    require(data.length >= 32, "Response must be > 32 bytes");
    bytes32 firstDataWord;
    assembly {
      firstDataWord := calldataload(data.offset)
    }
    require(requestId == firstDataWord, "First word must be requestId");
    _;
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the version of compiler and source code of the operator.sol? I compiled operator smart contract and did not get the issue.

Comment: Compiler version is 0.7.0, getting the same error in Hardhat and Remix. This is where  I got Operator.sol: https://github.com/EverID/everest-chainlink-consumer/blob/master/contracts/Operator.sol Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contract compiled with 0.7.6.